# Getting called id from Cisco IVR using TCL

Tags: tcl, cisco, ivr

How can I get called id (the number which the caller has dialed) from Cisco IVR command using TCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs at http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/voicesw/ps2192/products_programming_reference_guide09186a00800e9ab8.html the command appears to be:

```
dnis
```

(it "Returns the destination number")

Comment: Perhaps [`infotag get leg_dnis`](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/voice/tcl/developer/guide/tclivrv2_ch4.html#wp1050831) in v2 of the API?